# Transfer Rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have something like this in the xml

```
c1.1    test
c1.2    10
c1.3    100
c2.1    test1
c2.2    10
c2.3    1000
```

and i want to transform into like this

```
test    10  100
test1   10  1000
```

Please help .I tried with pivot and could not crack it .Need to mention here that c1.1 ,c1.2,c1.3  is a series and these 3 has to be in i row

Comment: Sounds like a typical pivot to me. Another methodology for this is a crosstab which is what I prefer as the syntax is less obtuse and the performance is generally slightly better. You sometimes hear of crosstabs being referred to as "conditional aggregates".

Comment: Post your PIVOT attempt and the error you got with it so we can help you debug it.

Comment: chemicalKeyName chemicalValueName 
(1) Chemical Name: efef 
(1) Chemical Percentage: 24 
(1) CAS #:

 row   1 2 3 
(1) CAS #:  NULL NULL NULL 
(1) Chemical Name: NULL NULL NULL 
(1) Chemical Percentage:NULL NULL NULL 



This is what i am getting .used query is 


select * from ( select left(ChemicalKeyName,29) as row, right(ChemicalKeyName, 45) as col, ChemicalValueName from @temp ) S pivot ( max(ChemicalValueName) for col in ([1], [2], [3]) ) P

Comment: have just posted my pivot attempt

Comment: what XML? Why not present the full problem by providing the data as XML? and, place the full attempted pivot query into the question (not a comment)

Answer (score 0):

Pivot will do exactly what you want, something like this:

```
select * from (
  select left(type,2) as row, right(type, 1) as col, value 
  from Table1
) S pivot (
  max(value) for col in ([1], [2], [3])
) P
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/648c8/1)

Comment: chemicalKeyName chemicalValueName
(1) Chemical Name:        efef
(1) Chemical Percentage: 24
(1) CAS #:    


row   1 2 3
(1) CAS #:  NULL NULL NULL
(1) Chemical Name: NULL NULL NULL
(1) Chemical Percentage:NULL NULL NULL                               This is what i am getting .used query is select * from (
  select left(ChemicalKeyName,29) as row, right(ChemicalKeyName, 45) as col, ChemicalValueName 
  from @temp
) S pivot (
  max(ChemicalValueName) for col in ([1], [2], [3])
) P

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e28d0/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Code] varchar(20), [Value] varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Code], [Value])
VALUES
    ('c1.1', 'test'),
    ('c1.2', '10'),
    ('c1.3', '100'),
    ('c2.1', 'test1'),
    ('c2.2', '10'),
    ('c2.3', '1000')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
      Value1, Value2, Value3
from (
      select
             Value as Value1
           , lead(Value,1) over(partition by left(t1.code,charindex('.',t1.code)-1)
                                order by substring(t1.code,charindex('.',t1.code)+1,len(t1.code))) as Value2
           , lead(Value,2) over(partition by left(t1.code,charindex('.',t1.code)-1)
                                order by substring(t1.code,charindex('.',t1.code)+1,len(t1.code))) as Value3

      from table1 t1
     ) as derived
where Value3 is not null
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e28d0/1/0)**:

```
| Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
|--------|--------|--------|
|   test |     10 |    100 |
|  test1 |     10 |   1000 |
```

Answer (score 0):

In SqlServer 2008 Schema Set Up we can do using Row_number. basing on the sample data i have given this code.

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    (val varchar(4), col varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (val, col)
VALUES
    ('c1.1', 'test'),
    ('c1.2', '10'),
    ('c1.3', '100'),
    ('c2.1', 'test1'),
    ('c2.2', '10'),
    ('c2.3', '1000')
;
Select [1] as [Value1],[2] as [Value2],[3] as [Value3]from (
select SUBSTRING(reverse(val),0,CHARINDEX('.',Reverse(val))) R,
col
,ROW_Number()OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(reverse(val),0,CHARINDEX('.',reverse(val))) Order by val) RN
 from @Table1)T
PIVOT(max(col) for R IN ([1],[2],[3]))PVT
```

Comment: @joe it's a late answer .Just try once if this is what you are looking for